# Linting not capturing context values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I have the following code.

`myContext.js`

```
import React from 'react';

export default React.createContext();
```

This is then used in following.

`wrapper.jsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider, Consumer } from './myContext';

export const MyProvider = Provider;

export const Wrapper = (Component) => {
  const Wrapper = props => (
    <Consumer>
      {value => <Component {...props}/>}
    </Consumer>
  );
  return Wrapper;
};
```

All the above works fine.

But when I run `npm run eslint -- --ext js,jsx .`, I get the following error.

```
/Users/name/my-proj/src/utils/wrapper.jsx
  error  Provider not found in './myContext'  import/named
  error  Consumer not found in './myContext'  import/named
```

Why? And how could I make the lint pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is exporting an object from `./myContext` that has `Provider` and `Consumer` keys, but that's **not the same** as exporting things with the name `Provider` and `Consumer`. Under the old days of `require()` that was the same thing, but these days you need to explicitly export each one - that way the linter can verify that the things you're importing actually exist.

```
const context = React.createContext();
export const Provider = context.Provider;
export const Consumer = context.Consumer;
```

This may seem like extra work but is worth it to avoid bugs (IMO).

Another nice trick I like to do when creating a context is to export a React hook so make consuming easier:

```
export const useMyContext = () => useContext(myContext);
```